# Intern - window is undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, intern

I have a loop of tests running in intern-geezer, with about twenty out of a hundred very similar tests running successfully. Then suddenly:

```
FATAL ERROR
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

and the loop stops. There are no explicit calls to `window` or `document` in my code. It's pure JS. I'm using intern-geezer, 2.2.2. The line numbers referenced in the error stack make absolutely no sense. They're way off.

I've read the suggestion to switch from the command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern
```

to:

```
./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern
```

but I don't want to connect to a server or open a browser (there's a separate, strange loading error occurring there which seems specific to geezer). I want to get this going at the command line. Grateful for any help, I'm totally new to Intern.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using geezer if you only want to run tests in the Node client? Geezer only exists to be able to run tests in older browsers.

Comment: Well, I do eventually want to be able to run tests in old IE. First things first, I'd like to get basic unit tests working.

Answer (score 1):

`window` is a browser object, so it's not going to be available in Node. If you want to run tests exclusively in the node client (`intern-client`), you'll need to make sure you're not using (and none of your dependencies are using) any code that references browser objects like `document`, `window`, `navigator`, etc.

If the stack trace line numbers are off, it's probably the code coverage instrumentation. You can disable that by setting the `excludeInstrumentation` property in your Intern config to `/./`.

Comment: None of my code (or my one dependency) makes any calls to window, document, or navigator. And the tests are very similar. Why would some run and not the others? It's not a syntax error. I've spent an entire afternoon scouring the tests, and tried commenting out various combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set 'Html' as reporter in your intern configuration file :

```
intern.reporters = [
    { id: 'Html' },
    { id: 'JUnit', filename: 'test-reports/quality/functional/junit.xml' },
    ...,
];
```